# scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN); always is triggered

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

OK,i have ScrollView with multiply recyclerview-s.When user click on some item on my list that item expand itself with some more info. The problem is that although it does expand correctly, my root view(in my case ScrollView) does not follow that expansion automatically ,so i need to scroll manually to see expanded item.So i used `scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN)` in onClick in my recyclerview.And it works fine but after this line of code is triggered every other click on some other recycelerView it scroll down although that recyclerview does not have fullScroll().

I tried to use `scrollTo()`,`smoothScrollTo` etc.I dont use ExpandableRecyclerView but ***cachapa/ExpandableLayout*** and in this [thread](https://github.com/cachapa/ExpandableLayout/issues/13) developer said that it is rather the parent View "issue".Also tried solution from the same thread but problem persist.

So my question is how to stop triggering fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN) when i click on other recuclerviews items.

my code:

```
`  animaton.setOnClickListener(v -> {

                notifyDataSetChanged();
                //some stuff

                    scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
                        }
                    });
            });`
```